# Fetch user information with Facebook PHP api?

Tags: php, facebook

I just managed to connect to the facebook PHP api. Facebook API tutorial seems really bad or at least poorly organized.

I realised I can get the logged in user's name with: `<?php print_r($user_profile[name]); ?>` since it's beforehand set as `$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');` . How do I print another user's name who is not logged in, knowing his UID, for example '2222'

How do I fetch user info, specifically name and UID?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What user do you want to fetch ? You can fetch current user with /me. Before using the Facebook PHP API , you need to understand about Facebook [graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). It explain everything about Facebook api access url. So, you can call the graph URL in Facebook PHP SDK.

You can check sample source code from

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/

```
require './facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, actually what I'm asking is easier. I realised I can get the logged in user's name with: `<?php print_r($user_profile[name]); ?>` since it's beforehand set as `$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');` . How do I print another user's name who is not logged in, knowing his UID, for example '2222'

Comment: you can call $facebook->api('/220439'); , it's the same with $facebook->api('/btaylor'). You can check url , https://graph.facebook.com/220439

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
          FB.init({appId: <?php echo FACEBOOK_APP_ID;?>, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
          FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {});
          FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function(response) { 
            if (response.session) { 

              FB.api('/me', function(response) {             
                 if(response.id!='undefined')
                 {  
                    window.location='Fbaccess.php?first_name='+response.first_name+'&last_name='+response.last_name+'&email='+response.email;
                 }
                 else
                 {  
                    window.location='login.php';
                 }
                }); 

            } else {

              // The user has logged out, and the cookie has been cleared
            }
          });

        </script>
```

php code ....

```
<?php 
$cookie = get_facebook_cookie(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_SECRET);        
if(isset($cookie))
{
    $first_name = json_decode(@file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' .$cookie['access_token']))->first_name;
    $last_name = json_decode(@file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' .$cookie['access_token']))->last_name;
} 
?>


function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $application_secret) 
{
  $args = array();
  parse_str(trim($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id], '\\"'), $args);
  ksort($args);
  $payload = '';
  foreach ($args as $key => $value) 
  {
    if ($key != 'sig') {
      $payload .= $key . '=' . $value;
    }
  }
  if (md5($payload . $application_secret) != $args['sig']) {
    return null;
  }
  return $args;
}
```

i think this much code is available for you to get facebook name and user id ....
on this url you will find whole response

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' .$cookie['access_token']

Comment: Thanks, actually what I'm asking is easier. I realised I can get the logged in user's name with: `<?php print_r($user_profile[name]); ?>` since it's beforehand set as `$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');` . How do I print another user's name who is not logged in, knowing his UID, for example '2222'

Answer (score 0):

In your api call, replace the '/me' with '/2222'